# A city bus in Redmond, Washington contained 29 passengers.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A survey revealed that their average yearly income was $\$40,000$, they had a unique median income of $\$38,000$. (a) How large could the maximum income be? (b) The mode of their yearly income was also $\$38,000$, for two passengers earned exactly that, and one passenger earned just seventeen dollars more, $\$38,017$. Then Bill Gates boarded the bus. His income that year was $\$30,000,000$. What changes in the mean, median, and mode did his boarding cause?

This is what I have:

(a) Since the average is $\$40,000$, then we can say that $\bar{x}= \frac{\text{total income}}{n}$

$\rightarrow \$40,000 = \frac{x}{29} \rightarrow \$1,160,000=$ total income.

Then we can say that the first 14 people have an income of $\$0$ and the 15$^{th}$ person = $\$38,000$ and the persons $15< x \leq 28 = \$38,000.01$

So we get something like this: $14*0+\$38,000+13*\$38,000.01+x=\$1,160,000$

$\rightarrow \$532,000.13+x=\$1,160,000 \rightarrow x= \$627,999.87$

So the maximum income would be $\$627,999.87$

I'll update on section (b), but for now is (a) okay?

Comment: that is for part (b) though

Comment: True.  I missed that.

Comment: That's how I would do the problem. With fractional pennies of salary, the answer would converge to 628,000, but since those don't exist in the real world, your answer is the one I'd give.